# Unable to see the embedded fonts in Ibook 3.0.2

Tags: epub, ibooks

I have created an epub 3.0 file which has font embedding as follows

```
     @font-face{
               font-family:Myfont;
               font-weight:normal;
               font-style:normal;
               src:url("Fonts/footfont.otf");
               }
```

and i am applying the fonts to the tag as follows:

```
    p{
      font-family:"Myfont";
      font-size:12pt;
     }
```

i have also included the com.apple.ibooks.display-options.xml to META-INF. I can see my 
embedded fonts in ADE but i can't see it in ipod iTouch. what can be the reason.can anyone help?.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding:

```
<meta property="ibooks:specified-fonts">true</meta>
```

to the .opf file? (iBookstoreAssetGuide5.1.pdf page 26)